# Create a webservice that connects to another webservice every hour to update my DB

Tags: web-services, web-applications, programming-languages, webserver

I want to create a weather app for my android phone but now I got stuck on the backend part of the app.

I have found a weatherservice where I can, for free, get detailed information about a certain location through their webservice. But they have stated in their rules that I am not allowed to poll their service with a high frequency. So I thought that I could create a webservice on my own that retrieve weatherinformation from the weatherstation that I found and then make it available through my webservice so that my app only make calls to my service.

the communication will be like below

MyApp <--> MyWebService <--> commercial webservice

the android app talks to MyWebService. And my webservice talks to the commercial service.

So I want MyWebService to do to things.

1. retrieve information from the commercial webservice once every hour and update my database
2. handle requests from my androidApp

My problem is that I know to little about web application and web services. I don't really know what language to choose for the webservice.
PHP with soap or REST looks like a good candidate for the second task. But I can't find any sample on how to handle the first task. Is there any easy way to tell the server to run my script once every hour?
I have been looking a litle into C# as well which would suit me a litle bit more as I am more used to C#. But the same question arise here. How do I handle the second task?

This is something that I wanted to write for a long time, but I feel totaly lost here.

Comment: On your server you'd probably want _two_ applications, sharing one database.  The web service application would handle requests for data and respond with what's currently in the database.  The second application would be a back-end script, console application, Windows service, scheduled task of some kind which polls the vendor's service and updates the database.

Answer (score 1):

Doing things "once an hour" (or more generally, scheduling tasks) from a web-only application is tricky for a number of reasons.  It is much better in general to use the built-in mechanism of the operating system to perform scheduled tasks (e.g. *cron* under Linux, or *Scheduled Tasks* under Windows), or to write a service/daemon process that handles the updates.

Having said that, there is a fairly straightforward way to meet your requirement.  You can *cache* the result of the commercial web service in your web application tier, along with a timestamp of the last time you retrieved the information.  When a web request comes into your web service from your app, first check the timestamp of the cache.  If the timestamp is less than one hour old, just returned the cached weather data.  If the timestamp is more than an hour, call the commercial web service directly from there, write the result and the current time into your cache, and return the data you just got to the app.

PHP is certainly well-suited to this kind of task.  Detailed instructions on how to do that are beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question.  Google for PHP and caching, try out some examples, and ask detailed follow-up questions if you get stuck.